# AngularJS ng-if with fixed element position

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given a scenario with two elements, where the first element is only displayed if it meets a specific condition ng-if, then the second element will move up or down depending on whether the first element is present.

```
<body ng-app="ngAnimate">
  <label>Click me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true" /></label>
  <p ng-if="checked" class="variable">Variable Element</p>
  <br/>
  <p class="fixed">Fixed Element</p>
</body>
```

What would be the best way to display the second element in a fixed position, without it depending on the presence of the first element? Or even better, leave sufficient space to display the first element when it is visible?

What I've tried so far is to set the second element's placement via CSS. It works, but is most probably not the best solution.

```
.fixed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  border:1px solid green;
  padding:10px;
}
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4OXYlB7q3296snu6G1ow?p=preview).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ng-if`, use `visibility: hidden` in combination with a styled `ng-class` or a plain `ng-style` directive.

The visibility CSS attribute preserves any space allocated for displaying the element, which seems to fit your use case better than absolute positioning.

Here : http://plnkr.co/edit/m7FI3BjHJWKbUzSDfjlp?p=preview.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle), for example:

```
<p class="fixed" ng-style="{top: checked ? '100px' : '20px'}">Fixed Element</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-class to set the class of the paragraph based on whether checked is true or false.

```
<p ng-class="{checked : 'fixed'}">Fixed Element</p>
```